# Fetching data from a .json file and displaying onto a .HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am so confused that i don't even know where to begin...

i will give the best description of what i am having to do.
I am having to fetch data from a .json file (test.json) and display the data from that .json file to a .html document (index.html).

the data i am fetching is only one value.

all I know is that you have to reference it with something like

```
<p id="jsondata"></p>
```

this is the only knowledge i have of how to reference .json files. i know that i might use javascript to turn the data into a DOM reference, but i will put it simply. I have NO clue.

Sorry for the Vague question Stack Overflow.

Comment: i have tried some code for something called .stringify. but it is for a table. i want a single value..

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
const element = document.querySelector('#jsondata');
fetch('/test.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseJSON => element.textContent = JSON.stringify(responseJSON))
```

though it really depends on how you want to format it in said element.

Comment: thank you for this, i will try messing with it in a few mins.

Answer (score 0):

simple exame is here

html file

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" > </script>
<script>
    $(function() {
    var people = [];
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
            "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" +"<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
        });
        });
    });     
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="profile">
<table id= "userdata" border="2">
<thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
    </thead>
  <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

data.json

```
    {
    "person": [
        {
            "firstName": "Clark",
            "lastName": "Kent",
            "job": "Reporter",
            "roll": 20
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Bruce",
            "lastName": "Wayne",
            "job": "Playboy",
            "roll": 30
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Peter",
            "lastName": "Parker",
            "job": "Photographer",
            "roll": 40
        }
    ]
}
```

may it'll help you well.
don't just copy this code please understand too.